# What is mean "CMOS compatible wireless link"?

Tags: cmos

In wireless communication (Chip) this expression is mostly used "CMOS technology compatible wireless links", what means this statement ?

Comment: I agree with Tony's answer, but it's more of an educated guess. It would really be necessary to add a reference to *where* you've read that.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this means that the circuitry required to implement the transmitter and receiver can be implemented on a standard CMOS process alongside other high performance digital logic, as oppposed to requiring a more specialized analog process that is more expensive/less suited to integration alongside high performance CMOS logic.  It is much more difficult to design analog circuitry that works well on a CMOS process than it is to implement the same functionality on an analog optimized process.  This sort of thing is very important when building highly integrated system on chips, where a high performance processor can be integrated along with all of its major peripherals (not just serial ports, but things like mobile GPUs, wi-fi, bluetooth, etc.) on one piece of silicon.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the **design is compatible with CMOS fabrication process** as opposed to Silicon Bipolar or Gallium Arsenide or Gallium Nitride or Silicon-Germanium.

This allows special Microwave chipsets such as SDR and GPS to be made and circuits such as "deep sub-micron CMOS process compatible high Q on-chip spiral inductors with air gap structure "  or "quadrature oscillator with 0.18 μm CMOS technology."